# Intellij 2020.3 Apple Silicon install Android SDK failure

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apple-silicon

I'm trying to install the Android SDK using the Intellij Community edition (2020.3) on my mac running Apple Silicon. I have downloaded the newly released Intellij for ARM and is trying to install the SDK using the Intellij SDK setup (launched when creating a new Android project).

However, when trying to install the SDK I get the following error message (see screenshot):

```
An error occurred while trying to compute required packages.
```

In the terminal I see two exceptions:

```
2021-01-06 09:52:35,395 [ 562239]   WARN - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Failed to find a valid embedded JDK
java.lang.Error: Incomplete or corrupted installation - "/Applications/prebuilts/studio/jdk/jdk11/mac/Contents/Home" directory does not exist
```

followed by

```
2021-01-06 09:53:07,896 [ 594740]   WARN - precated.InstallComponentsPath - Dependant package with key emulator not found!
com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils$PackageResolutionException: Dependant package with key emulator not found!
```

If I try to install the Android SDK manually, I simply get the second error message as well when I try to install the build-tools: `Dependant package with key emulator not found!`.

I know that the emulator does not exist for Apple Silicon, but I should still be able to install the build-tools and debug using a physical device, right?

Comment: have you try to use the Intellij 2021 EAP version? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252775#focus=Comments-27-4617076.0-0

Answer (score 3):

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate]

It happens in **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate** too.
I have installed the Android SDK with Android Studio; but, IntelliJ is not able to launch android applications in physical devices.

Comment: Same for me, can't launch any project on real device (already April of 2021)

Comment: @brucemax IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 is out! It should work now with this update.

Comment: Yep, launches successfully in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same error with IntelliJ IDEA CE 2021.1. I installed the SDK manually with sdkmanager, but if I try to edit the SDK location I get the same error (An error occurred while trying to compute required packages.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Android support in current version of IntelliJ IDEA Community does not yet have any Apple Silicon support.

Here is an Android Studio article about the initial support for Emulator for Apple Silicon: [Android Emulator Apple Silicon Preview](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html). The article contains the link to an image and instructions to install.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to install the emulator from that page manually as well. But still I can't install the build-tools . I get the same error..